# change account domian for straoslive

Tags: dns, wso2

I have a wso2 stratos live account and would like to change the account domain. I go to the account settings page and I see the field for the domain, but I can not change the value. I can change the value of other fields, such as my contact info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenant domain is a unique ideantity to the Stratos account. All the users of the tenant will be of the form {user-name}@{domain-name}.

By design, it can not be changed.

Comment: Thank you Pradeebah. Validating the domain is not needed and is only for prove ownership should someone else claim it.